# Plotting and labelling graph of greatest integer function using LaTeX picture environment

Tags: graphics, plot, picture-mode

I want to plot and label the graph of greatest integer function f(x) = [x + 1] on the interval [−2, 2].
Using LATEX picture environment

Comment: Welcome to TSE. If you want to use the LaTeX picture environment, that what has your question to do with [tag:pstricks] or with [tag:includegraphics]?

Comment: Any news? You receive three answers, you can accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) which the best fulfill your expectations.

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution with use of the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$
              ]
    \addplot [samples at={-2,-1,...,2}, const plot] {ceil(x+1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that this function is drawing as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$f(x)$,
              ]
    \addplot +[thick, samples at={-2,-1,...,2},
               jump mark left] {ceil(x+1)};
    \addplot  [thick, samples at={-1,0,...,2}, only marks,
               mark options={draw=blue,fill=white}] {(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now it is correct ahahah. Before I see the ladder ahahah :-)

Comment: How can you change the graph to red?  I have been trying but can't figure it out. How do you remove the dot in the upper corner?

Comment: @NickB:  `    \addplot  [red, thick, samples at={-2,-1,...,2},
               mark options={fill=red},
               jump mark left] {ceil(x+1)};
    \addplot  [thick, samples at={-1,0,...,2}, only marks,
               mark options={draw=red,fill=white}] {(x)};
`

Comment: Why does there seem to be two extra points in each corner? Is there a way of correcting this?

Answer (score 3):

Plain Ti*k*Z solution, which you can adapt for further application.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={f(\x)=\x+1;},
        start/.style={blue,draw,circle, minimum width=3pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=white},
        end/.style={blue,circle, minimum width=3pt,inner sep=0pt, fill=blue}]
        
        \def\xmin{-2.5} \def\xmax{2.5}
        \def\ymin{-2.5} \def\ymax{2.5}
        
        \draw[-stealth] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node [above left] {$x$};
        \draw[-stealth] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node [below right] {$y$};
        
        \foreach \i in {-2,...,1}
            {
            \draw [blue](\i,{f(\i)}) node[start] {} --++ (1,0) node[end] {};
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: greatest integer function]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple solution using the actual `picture` environment --- I'm not sure this is the function you actually *want* to plot, but it should serve as a template if nothing else.

You probably don't need to load `pict2e` here, but I've found it useful in general when using this environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{2cm}
    \begin{picture}(5,5)(-2.5,-2.5)
        \thicklines
        % Axes
        \put(0,-2.5){\vector(0,1){5}}
        \put(-0.4,2){\makebox(0.5,0.5){$y$}}
        \put(-2.5,0){\vector(1,0){5}}
        \put(2,-0.4){\makebox(0.5,0.5){$x$}}
        % Segments of the function
        \put(-2,-1){\circle{0.08}}
        \put(-1.96,-1){\line(1,0){0.96}}
        \put(-1,-1){\circle*{0.08}}
        \put(-1,0){\circle{0.08}}
        \put(-0.96,0){\line(1,0){0.96}}
        \put(0,0){\circle*{0.08}}
        \put(0,1){\circle{0.08}}
        \put(0.04,1){\line(1,0){0.96}}
        \put(1,1){\circle*{0.08}}
        \put(1,2){\circle{0.08}}
        \put(1.04,2){\line(1,0){0.96}}
        \put(2,2){\circle*{0.08}}
    \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

However, I would generally consider using TikZ or something similar instead.